# Apply global setting for all activities C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to apply this setting `Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);` to all activities in my Xamarin Android Application without copying from every activity.

Comment: Subclass the Activity type that you are using, add that code in the `OnCreate` and then use this new subclass for your applications activities.

Comment: Thank you, it is working